# Jquery spams timestamp when typing a question mark?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an application where you post messages to the system. Whenever you just type question marks, the message gets turned into:

> jQuery16104892938028
>   4552626_132040318254
>   1

I have no idea how to debug this or why it happens. What could be a possible cause?

```
window.post = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'includes/library/ajax/sbpost.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'msg=' + $('#sbmsg').val() + '&sbl=' + sbl,
        success: function(msg){
            $('#sbmsg').val('');
            sbl = msg.sbl;
            var i = msg.old.length;
            var c = 0;
            $('#sbmsgs').append(msg.newmsgs);
            for (x in msg.old) {
                $('#sb-post-'+msg.old[x]).slideUp();
                $('#sb-post-'+msg.newids[x]).slideDown();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have no idea as well, but for sure you're using wrong way to send data to the server.

Use this to set `data` value:

```
data: {
    msg: $('#sbmsg').val(),
    sbl: sbl
}
```

Comment: Arhh that was the problem then. It works now I've changed it to like that :D Thanks!